# How to import predefined decision tree and use it for classification

Tags: python, parsing, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

## Long story short

As an input I have a file with text representation of simple decision tree:

```
Region in [ "someregion" ]
    Revenue <= 1020.30
        group in [ "audio" ] => 123.456
        group in [ "disc" ] => 123.456
            volume <= 1 => 734.25
...
```

The program should import it as a classifier and be able to predict object's value. In other words, for object like following:

```
{"Region": "someregion", "Revenue": 100, "group": "disc", "volume": 0.5}
```

the prediction will be `734.25`.

What existing decision tree implementations can I use to create a classifier? `SciKit` trees is almost the thing, but I didn't find a way to build a custom predefined trees instead of fitting on a dataset.

## My attempt

For now I implement a simple tree parser:

```
import re

def parse_condition(row):
    # try with leaf regex
    condition = re.search(
        r'^(?P<field>.*?) (?P<statement>.*?) (?P<value>.*?)(?: => )(?P<target>\d*\.\d*)',
        row
    ) or re.search(
        r'^(?P<field>.*?) (?P<statement>.*?) (?P<value>.*?)',
        row)
    return condition.groupdict()

f = open('tree.txt', 'r')

for row in f.readlines():
    level = len(re.search(r'^(\t*)', row).group(0))
    row = row.strip()
    condition = parse_condition(row)
    el = (level, condition)
    print(el)
```

which extracts node level, condition and target value.

```
(0, {'field': 'Region', 'statement': 'in', 'value': ''})
(1, {'field': 'Revenue', 'statement': '<=', 'value': ''})
(2, {'field': 'group', 'statement': 'in', 'value': '[ "audio" ]', 'target': '123.456'})
(2, {'field': 'group', 'statement': 'in', 'value': '[ "disc" ]', 'target': '123.456'})
(3, {'field': 'volume', 'statement': '<=', 'value': '1', 'target': '734.25'})
```

Although I can develop a custom decision tree and condition parser from scratch, it seems like attempt to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It exists a format named [PMML, Predictive Model Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language). You can store decissions trees in this format to avoid to reinvent the wheel.

For example, [knime software](https://www.knime.com/) is able to deal with this format [Example for Learning a Decision Tree](https://www.knime.com/nodeguide/analytics/classification-and-predictive-modelling/example-for-learning-a-decision-tree). A PMML decision tree looks like [this example](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/lightpmmlpredictor/blob/master/pmml-models/dt.pmml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PMML version="4.1" xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_1">
  <Header copyright="dani">
    <Application name="KNIME" version="2.7.2"/>
  </Header>
  <DataDictionary numberOfFields="7">
    <DataField name="nom_nivell" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
      <Value value="ESO"/>
      ...
      <Value value="CFGM Infor"/>
    </DataField>
    <DataField name="hora_inici" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
      <Value value="09:15:00"/>
      ...
      <Value value="13:45:00"/>
    </DataField>
    ...
  </DataDictionary>
  <TreeModel modelName="DecisionTree" functionName="classification" splitCharacteristic="multiSplit" missingValueStrategy="lastPrediction" noTrueChildStrategy="returnNullPrediction">
    <MiningSchema>
      <MiningField name="nom_nivell" invalidValueTreatment="asIs"/>
      <MiningField name="hora_inici" invalidValueTreatment="asIs"/>
      <MiningField name="assistenciaMateixaHora1WeekBefore" invalidValueTreatment="asIs"/>
      <MiningField name="assistencia" invalidValueTreatment="asIs" usageType="predicted"/>
    </MiningSchema>
    <Node id="0" score="Present" recordCount="244770.0">
      <True/>
      <ScoreDistribution value="Present" recordCount="211657.0"/>
      <ScoreDistribution value="Absent" recordCount="24925.0"/>
          ...
```

Graphically it looks like this on Knime:

[image]

Then, the easy way to figure up results rom a PMML is using tree traversals. I posted on [my githup repo lightpmmlpredictor](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/lightpmmlpredictor) an utility to do it. The core is a simple while traversing nodes using `etree` from `lxml`:

```
while True:

    try:        

        fill = next( e for e in Node 
                     if etree.QName(e).localname == 'Node' and
                        unicode(values[ e[0].get('field') ]) == e[0].get('value') )

        try:
            Node = fill
            predict = Node.get("score")
            n_tot = Node.get("recordCount")
            n_predict = max(  x.get( 'recordCount' ) 
                              for x in Node 
                              if etree.QName(x).localname == 'ScoreDistribution'   
                                 and x.get('value') == predict )
        except IndexError:
            break

        try:
            pct = float(n_predict) / float(n_tot)
        except:
            pct = 0.5
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Be free to contribute to or fork my repo.

Comment: it seems that you posted exactly what I need, thank you:)